# Pyramid Triangles

Tags: contest-math, triangles, 3d

A pyramid has a triangular base, length $300$ and has a height (center of the equilateral triangle to the vertex) of $100$. I climb the edge of the pyramid to the top and I have covered $138$ cm, what is my altitude?

I have tried using the approach of similar triangles, the center of the equilateral triangle connected to a vertex has length $50\sqrt3$, then the length of the edge must be $\sqrt{10000 + 75000} = 50$ $\sqrt7$. Using similar triangles, the ratio was - $50 \sqrt7 /100 = 138/\text{altitude}$ which is wrong.

from sipnayan 2017

Comment: Is this an active competition (I assume in the Philippines)? If so, I'm afraid we can't (shouldn't) help till the contest/exam is over.

Comment: By your eighteenth post, you should definitely be using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may be part of an active contest (not been confirmed).

Comment: No. The contest is on November, 11

Comment: @Raffaele So this is a past question? It does not affect a current or future result?

Comment: The contest is already over

Comment: I'm sorry if im not using math jax, ill try to learn it for my next post,  the contest is yearly and is finished in one day

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I've answered below. Sorry I didn't post a diagram, but another answer did include one. I hope my wording is clear enough.

Comment: I've also retracted my close vote and upvoted for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find distance from vertex to centre of base.

Answer (score 1):

The side is $VB=\sqrt{100^2+(100\sqrt{3})^2}=200$

because $BH=\frac23 h$

[image]

Comment: wait it says on Brilliant https://brilliant.org/wiki/properties-of-equilateral-triangles/ that the length of an altitude is s x root3/2 so the BH is 25 root 3?

Comment: The side is $300$ then $h=150\sqrt{3}$ and $BH=\frac{2}{3}h=100\sqrt 3$ for the property of the baricenter of a triangle

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've clarified this is a past competition, I can help.

Consider the right triangle formed by height of pyramid (from apex of pyramid to base, which is the centre of the equilateral base) - which also constitutes "height" of this right triangle, the edge of the pyramid (the "hypotenuse" of this triangle) and the line segment connecting the vertex of the base to the center of the base (let's call that the "base" of the right triangle).

The last line segment ("base" of right triangle) is $\frac 23$ the length of the height of the base equilateral triangle (centroid theorem). The height of the base triangle is $300\cos 30^{\circ} = 150\sqrt 3$. So the length of the "base" is $\frac 23 \cdot 150\sqrt 3 = 100\sqrt 3$.

By Pythagoras' theorem, the "hypotenuse" of the right triangle (also the edge of the pyramid) is $\sqrt{(100\sqrt 3)^2 + 100^2} = 200$

Hence, by similar triangles, the altitude you require is $\frac{139}{200} \cdot 100 = 69.5$.

Comment: The wrong was that I used 1/2 not 2/3, thats why i got 50 root 3, Thanks!

Comment: No prob, centroid theorem is very useful in these cases. It applies to any triangle. The good thing about the special case of the equilateral triangle is that all the "centres" (incentre, circumcentre, orthocentre and centroid) are coincident (all the same point), so there's an unequivocal "centre" of the triangle.